# Find reverse order of an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

> Write a program that reads in a sequence of characters until the symbol * is encountered. Use a function that will display the sequence in reverse order. (Make use of arrays).

I have tried this, but I am getting an error:

> *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated

This as output:

```
Reverse order: �>
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char array[], int size);

int main()
{
    
    const int SIZE = 5;
    char c;
    char array[SIZE];
    
    cout << "Enter a character(OR Enter * to exit): "<< endl;
    
    while(c != '*')
    {
        cin >> c;
        array[SIZE] = c;
    }
    
    reverse(array, SIZE);
    
}

void reverse(char array[],int size)
{
    int i;
    cout << "Reverse order: ";
    for(i = size-1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        cout << array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[SIZE] = c;` ? Sure? Always replacing an out-of-bounds position?

Comment: `array[SIZE] = c;` invokes undefined behavior. The array is only `SIZE` large, meaning indexible via 0..(SIZE-1) inclusively.

Comment: Since you are already doing it in C++ instead of C, just use vectors. They are the best when it comes to handling such dynamic size inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing out of bounds of the array, which is **undefined behavior**. You are corrupting surrounding memory.

Also, `c` is uninitialized when you try to read from it for the 1st time, which is also **undefined behavior**.

And, you are not validating that `operator>>` is successful before using `c` afterwards, which is also **undefined behavior** if `operator>>` fails.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverse(char array[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    char array[SIZE], c;
    int n = 0;
    
    cout << "Enter up to " << SIZE << " characters (OR enter * to exit): " << endl;
    
    while ((n < SIZE) && (cin >> c) && (c != '*'))
    {
        array[n++] = c;
    }
    
    reverse(array, n);
}

void reverse(char array[], int size)
{
    cout << "Reverse order: ";
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << array[i];
    }
}
```

That being said, this can be simplified a bit by using `std::string` and `std::getline()` instead of an array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void reverse(const string &s);

int main()
{
    string s;
    
    cout << "Enter characters (OR enter * to exit): " << endl;
    getline(cin, s, '*');

    reverse(s);
}

void reverse(const string &s)
{
    cout << "Reverse order: ";
    for(auto iter = s.rbegin(); iter != s.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using `string`, why write a separate reverse function for it. Just use the in-built one. `reverse(s.begin(), s.end());`

Comment: @risingStark you could, in this particular example. But in general, `std::reverse()` will *modify* the string, which may not always be desirable. This code merely wants to *display* the string in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(c != '*')
    {
        cin >> c;
        array[SIZE] = c;
    }
```

This is the first problem. You are trying to write at array[5] which is not allowed.
Also, use another varibale like `i` and update it to store every input.